# GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies failed unexpected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I just installed Xamarin 3.9.289 (newest version). When using both Visual Studio 2013 or Xamarin Studio, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error MSB4018: The "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() (MSB4018) (Xamarin.Droid)
```

What is the reason for this and how could I fix it?

Further info:

- Android SDK Tools: 24.0.2
- Android SDK Platform Tools: 21
- Android SDK Build Tools: 21.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my sample project was called "Xamarin" - looking at the disassembled code of the build dll shows that it is searching for that string internally and sadly starts from the left, not the right.

The fix is easy: Rename the project.

Answer (score 1):

`Xamarin.Android` applications use a **linker** in order to reduce the size of the application.The default value is `SdkOnly`

- `None`: No linking will be attempted.
- `SdkOnly`: Linking will be
  performed on the base class libraries only, not user's assemblies.
- `Full`: Linking will be performed on base class libraries and user
  assemblies.
  [For more details refer here..](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)
  Note: if you are facing an issue with linking such as

> LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. or
>
> "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: . Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

then recheck your xamarin.Android project settings and set the below tag,

```
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.4</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>true</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
```

Hope it will be helpful.